# How to traverse through a multi-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

This is the array I have, I would like to traverse through it and print the usernames one by one:

```
Array ( [0] => [{"username":"klara","id":"1","lev":0},
                {"username":"catherine","id":"8","lev":0},
                {"username":"eliz","id":"9","lev":0}] )
```

How should I go about it?

I tried this: `$arrayName[0][0]['username']`
But with no luck.

Thans for any help! :)

Comment: That looks like an JSONString representation of the data.

Comment: How did you produce that array print

Comment: How did you produce that array?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I actually received the array through the POST method and then did this: `$resultsArray=array($_POST['resultArray']);` and then used `print_r($resultsArray)`

Comment: So try this instead `$arr = json_decode($_POST['resultArray']); print_r($arr);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Okay I'll try..thanks so much for stopping by to help :)

Comment: @SahilGulati I didnt downvote, btw it was giving an error

Comment: @KlaraNewbie have you tried this code snippet https://eval.in/819016 ? It is working fine.

Comment: @SahilGulati You cannot just INVENT some quotes around that data to suit your answer. The data is being sent to this script as is and must be delt with as it appears

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is what I get now: `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [username] => klara [id] => 1 [lev] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [username] => catherine [id] => 8 [lev] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [username] => eliz [id] => 9 [lev] => 0 ))`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I didn't invented anything if you print an array containing JSON then it will give such output which is posted in the question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you check https://eval.in/819017 and correct me where i am wrong?

Comment: @SahilGulati, your answer worked! Thanks a lot! Thanks a lot to you too @RiggsFolly!! You guys are awesome!!

Comment: @SahilGulati there you go buddy..I just did :)